# MooTools - Detect the Array Index of the Class Clicked

Tags: javascript, mootools

Can anyone tell me how I can detect the array index of the class clicked.

So if I had:

HTML

```
<span class="test">first</span>
<span class="test">second</span>
<span class="test">third</span>
```

MooTools JS

```
$$('.test').addEvent('click', function(event){
       // alert(this array index);
});
```

Any help would be great,
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very simple - don't `.addEvent`, which will do the .each for you, but write the `.each` yourself instead, it supports `element, index`:

```
$$('.test').each(function(el, index) {
    el.addEvent('click', function(event){
       alert(index); // 0, 1, 2
    });
});
```